# For each row, find the cell that matches a specific string and return last character of column name

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

Here are some sample data. Each row is a different participant. Each participant completes five trials. In each trial, they pick one fruit from a set of 10 fruits (without replacement).

| ID | trial_1 | trial_2 | trial_3 | trial_4 | trial_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | apple | orange | banana | peach | grapes |
| 02 | grapes | watermelon | mango | peach | apricot |
| 03 | pear | grapes | mango | orange | banana |
| 04 | watermelon | apple | peach | grapes | pear |
| 05 | banana | peach | apple | grapes | mango |

I want to create 10 new columns--one for each fruit--that has the trial number in it (or "NA" if no trial number):

| ID | trial_1 | trial_2 | trial_3 | trial_4 | trial_5 | apple | apricot | banana | grapes | mango | orange | peach | pear | strawberries | watermelon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | apple | orange | banana | peach | grapes | 1 | NA | 3 | 5 | NA | 2 | 4 | NA | NA | NA |
| 02 | grapes | watermelon | mango | peach | apricot | NA | 5 | NA | 1 | 3 | NA | 4 | NA | NA | 2 |
| 03 | pear | grapes | mango | orange | banana | NA | NA | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | NA | 1 | NA | NA |
| 04 | watermelon | apple | peach | grapes | pear | 2 | NA | NA | 4 | NA | NA | 3 | 5 | NA | 1 |
| 05 | banana | peach | apple | grapes | mango | 3 | NA | 1 | 4 | 5 | NA | 2 | NA | NA | NA |

I could do that for each fruit column like this, but it seems very clunky:

```
mutate(apple = ifelse(trial_1 == "apple", 1,
               ifelse(trial_2 == "apple", 2,
               ifelse(trial_2 == "apple", 3,
               ifelse(trial_2 == "apple", 4
               ifelse(trial_2 == "apple", 5, "NA"))))))
```

I assume there is a much easier, neater solution to this, possibly using `rowwise()` to match the fruit name and then just returning the last character (i.e., the number) of the column name. But I just can't work it out. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  mutate(name = parse_number(name)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = name)
```

This would give the columns on the right. To append those to the original,

```
left_join(df, 
    # the code above
)
```

Result

```
Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 5 x 15
  ID    trial_1    trial_2    trial_3 trial_4 trial_5 apple orange banana peach grapes watermelon mango apricot  pear
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 01    apple      orange     banana  peach   grapes      1      2      3     4      5         NA    NA      NA    NA
2 02    grapes     watermelon mango   peach   apricot    NA     NA     NA     4      1          2     3       5    NA
3 03    pear       grapes     mango   orange  banana     NA      4      5    NA      2         NA     3      NA     1
4 04    watermelon apple      peach   grapes  pear        2     NA     NA     3      4          1    NA      NA     5
5 05    banana     peach      apple   grapes  mango       3     NA      1     2      4         NA     5      NA    NA
```

---

Source data:

```
tibble::tribble(
   ~ID,     ~trial_1,     ~trial_2, ~trial_3, ~trial_4,  ~trial_5,
  "01",      "apple",     "orange", "banana",  "peach",  "grapes",
  "02",     "grapes", "watermelon",  "mango",  "peach", "apricot",
  "03",       "pear",     "grapes",  "mango", "orange",  "banana",
  "04", "watermelon",      "apple",  "peach", "grapes",    "pear",
  "05",     "banana",      "peach",  "apple", "grapes",   "mango"
  ) -> df
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a vector of fruits in the order we wanted (in `base R`)

```
nm1 <- c("apple", "apricot", "banana", "grapes", "mango", "orange", 
         "peach", "pear", "strawberries", "watermelon")
```

Then loop over the rows of the data, use `match` to get the index and assign those as new columns

```
df1[nm1] <- t(apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) match(nm1, x)))
```

-output

```
df1
  ID    trial_1    trial_2 trial_3 trial_4 trial_5 apple apricot banana grapes mango orange peach pear strawberries watermelon
1  1      apple     orange  banana   peach  grapes     1      NA      3      5    NA      2     4   NA           NA         NA
2  2     grapes watermelon   mango   peach apricot    NA       5     NA      1     3     NA     4   NA           NA          2
3  3       pear     grapes   mango  orange  banana    NA      NA      5      2     3      4    NA    1           NA         NA
4  4 watermelon      apple   peach  grapes    pear     2      NA     NA      4    NA     NA     3    5           NA          1
5  5     banana      peach   apple  grapes   mango     3      NA      1      4     5     NA     2   NA           NA         NA
```

---

Or another `base R` option is

```
xtabs(ind ~ ID + values, transform(stack(df1[-1]), 
        ind = as.integer(sub(".*_", "", ind)), ID = df1$ID))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, trial_1 = c("apple", "grapes", "pear", 
"watermelon", "banana"), trial_2 = c("orange", "watermelon", 
"grapes", "apple", "peach"), trial_3 = c("banana", "mango", "mango", 
"peach", "apple"), trial_4 = c("peach", "peach", "orange", "grapes", 
"grapes"), trial_5 = c("grapes", "apricot", "banana", "pear", 
"mango")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another tidyverse solution for this question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

nm <- unique(unlist(df1[-1]))

df1 %>%
  bind_cols(nm %>%
              map_dfc(function(a) pmap_dbl(df1[, -1], ~ match(a, c(...)))) %>%
              set_names(nm))


  ID    trial_1    trial_2 trial_3 trial_4 trial_5 apple grapes pear watermelon banana orange
1  1      apple     orange  banana   peach  grapes     1      5   NA         NA      3      2
2  2     grapes watermelon   mango   peach apricot    NA      1   NA          2     NA     NA
3  3       pear     grapes   mango  orange  banana    NA      2    1         NA      5      4
4  4 watermelon      apple   peach  grapes    pear     2      4    5          1     NA     NA
5  5     banana      peach   apple  grapes   mango     3      4   NA         NA      1     NA
  peach mango apricot
1     4    NA      NA
2     4     3       5
3    NA     3      NA
4     3    NA      NA
5     2     5      NA
```